# MySQL, Separate Select Counting does not return the right sum of entries

Tags: mysql, select, count

I have this query:

```
SELECT `a`.`articleid`, `a`.`artno`, `a`.`name`, `a`.`descr`, `a`.`manufacturer`, `a`.`price-netto`, `a`.`taxid`, `a`.`stock`, `a`.`quantity`, `a`.`unit`, `a`.`statusid`, `sdcap`.`price-netto` AS `userprice`, 
       ( SELECT COUNT(*)
         FROM `bp_cart` AS `c`
         WHERE `c`.`customerid` = '63155252' AND `c`.`articleid` = `a`.`articleid`
         ) AS `totalcart`
FROM `bp_articles` AS `a`
LEFT JOIN `bp_sevdesk-customer-articleprices` AS `sdcap` ON `a`.`articleid` = `sdcap`.`articleid` AND `sdcap`.`customerid` = '63155252'
INNER JOIN `bp_orders-positions` AS `op` ON `a`.`articleid` = `op`.`articleid` AND `op`.`customerid` = '63155252'
INNER JOIN `bp_orders` AS `o` ON `o`.`orderid` = `op`.`orderid`
ORDER BY `o`.`adt` DESC
```

The result should be a list of articles in combination which had the user buy. The result ist okay. BUT: the additional select (count entries of cart) does return as result zero. There is one line in the cart with this customerid and articleid.

When sending the following query, i get as result 1:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `totalcart` 
FROM `bp_cart` AS `c` 
WHERE `c`.`customerid` = '63155252' AND `c`.`articleid` = '2517701'
```

Why does the first query combination does not work? It won't give me the right cart counts.

Comment: You see common join multiplying. Aggregate `bp_cart` only then use this subquery as one more datasource in FROM.